# How to make Python understand how a series of numbers continues

Tags: python

Hello and sorry in advance if my question is silly (I just started learning Python some weeks ago and it's my first programming language), but here it is anyways.
I was wondering if and how I can make Python understand how a series of numbers continues? For my current program, I have a line like this:

```
elif (inimeste_arv / kohtade_arv) in (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0):
```

Now, I want it to understand that it keeps going by the same meaning indefinitely (10.0, 11.0, 12.0 etc), because I can't manually enter every number this elif-statement needs.
Is there even a way to do it or is it not possible?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you looking to seek if `(inimeste_arv / kohtade_arv)` has a fractional part? If so: look at [modf](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.modf)

Comment: The result from the operation `(inimeste_arv / kohtade_arv)` has to be an _int_, but when dividing those numbers, it gives me a _float_ (for example 1.0, 2.0 etc). However, if I put an `int()` infront of this operation, it also makes _float_ s into _int_, but my program then fails to operate properly (its meant to only let pass integers, not _float_ s). I can post the full part of this program if it makes it any easier to understand - its a program where you enter a number of passengers and seats in a single bus and it tells you how many such buses do you need and how many sit in the last one.

Comment: pastebin.com/hrpJjhiY

It's in Estonian, I can translate it for you if it makes it any easier.

Note that it's just the part with my _elif_ statement, it's not my full program; if you also want that, I can provide it for you for better understanding.

inimeste_arv = number of people;

kohtade_arv = number of seats;

Viimases bussis inimesi = number of people in the last bus

Comment: Judging by the wide range of answers, no one really could understand what the issue was here. The closest seems to be find if the result is in a range which is a duplicate as indicated. If the poster clarifies the issue -- please post a new question. That is why we are here.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
elif (inimeste_arv / kohtade_arv) in map(float, range(1, number)):
```

where `number` is the `max value + 1`

Comment: Thanks King of Python! You should get a T-shirt with that statement.

Answer (score 0):

Always make the computers do the typing for you. I think we'd need a little more information to figure out an exact answer for you, but I have some guesses at what you're getting at.

One possibility I can surmise from your example is you want to know whether your result is an whole number. To test that, you could use the modulus operator (%), which gives you the remainder of a division operation:

```
124 % 5
Out: 4
125 % 5
Out: 0
```

So, if your (inimeste_arv / kohtade_arv) results in 0, you'll know it was a whole number.

Another possibility is you want to know if it's in a specific pattern of numbers. For a simple pattern, you could use range:

```
range(0, 125, 25)
Out: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100]
```

Which does have a finite end, but still saves you a lot of typing. For more complicated patterns, you might have read up on list comprehensions, which are very powerful but can be unintuitive for new programmers:

```
[i**2 for i in xrange(0, 6)]
Out: [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to see if the result of the division is an entire number, you can use the % operator.
Try:

```
elif (inimeste_arv % kohtade_arv) == 0:
```